# When voting to delete a post from a suggested edit when on the post, the confirmation is blank

Tags: bug, suggested-edits, moderator-tools

[image]

Comment: ​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​

Comment: ​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​